# Identiying repeating digits in Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of phone numbers in excel, some of which are obviously duds because they contain repeating digits like this '5555555'. Is there any easy way of identifying these?

Its Excel 2010.

Comment: you could try a VBA solution, such as described here: http://uk.queryclick.com/seo-news/searching-string-list-matches-excel/

Comment: or you can use a CSE formula as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313919/excel-search-for-a-list-of-strings-within-a-particular-string-using-array-formu

Comment: You would need to define your own list of "dud numbers": 555,111,999 etc

Answer (score 1):

This formula will return TRUE if value in A1 repeats any digit 7 times in a row, FALSE otherwise

`=COUNT(SEARCH(REPT({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},7),A1))>0`

adjust as required, e.g. replace 7 by required number